# How can I change Bootstrap 5 carousel indicators into dots?

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm using carousel bootstrap 5 for my site slider.my question it is how to change shape of carousel-indicators in bootstrap 5 similar this:
[image]

i searched in google but all answers was in older bootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this to your styles:

```
.carousel .carousel-indicators button {
    width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   border-radius: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this properties to CSS

```
.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target]{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just bit larger indicator

```
  .carousel .carousel-indicators button {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   border-radius: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target]{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

.carousel .carousel-indicators button {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   border-radius: 100%;
 }
```

The two solutions above are working fine, but if you put a background to the indicators, their shape is changing from circle to sphere..

Comment: .carousel .carousel-indicators button {
    width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   border-radius: 100%;
 }

this works fine with or without background color on the indicators